# Transforming a matrix with dimention (nxn) into matrix with combination of line*column

Tags: ubuntu, bioinformatics

I think that will be better examplify.

I have this structure of matrix (file):

**File1**

```
____   snp1  snp2   snp3   snp4
snp1    1     0.3   0.4    0.5
snp2    0.3     1   0.4    0.5
snp3    0.4   0.4     1    0.5
snp4    0.5   0.5   0.5      1
```

I wanted transform this **File1** into **File2**:

```
snp1 snp1   1
snp1 snp2   0.3 
snp1 snp3   0.4 
snp1 snp4   0.5
snp2 snp2   1 
snp2 snp3   0.4
snp2 snp4   0.5
snp3 snp3   1
snp3 snp4   0.5
snp4 snp4   1
```

I hope tha I were understandable, but I don't know other form to ask. 
In my real file is bigger then file1.

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking on Unix&Linux and not on Stackoverflow -- does this mean you want to avoid a "standard" programming language and work with unix shell tools?

Comment: So, as shown, you want to ignore values in the lower triangle i.e. for which the column index is less than the row index, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, but I wanted to ignorize because the values above triangle is equal to lower triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print only the upper triangular values as per your desired output

```
awk '
  NR==1 {
    split($0,hdr," "); next
  } 
  {
    for (i=NR;i<=NF;i++) {print $1 FS hdr[i] FS $i}
  }
' file
snp1 snp1 1
snp1 snp2 0.3
snp1 snp3 0.4
snp1 snp4 0.5
snp2 snp2 1
snp2 snp3 0.4
snp2 snp4 0.5
snp3 snp3 1
snp3 snp4 0.5
snp4 snp4 1
```

or equivalently, with perl

```
perl -alne '
  if ($. == 1) {
    @hdr = @F;
  } else {
    for $i ($.-1 .. $#F) {
      print join " ", $F[0], $hdr[$i], @F[$i];
    }
  }' file
```

If you want the full matrix instead of just the upper triangle, then modify the starting index of the `for` loop, replacing `NR` (in the awk version) by `2`, or `$.-1` (in the perl version) by `1`

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

No limitations now.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=File1
declare -a fields

fields=( $(head -n1 "$INPUT") )

i=0
while read -r line; do
    values=( $line )
    for ((j=++i; j<${#values[@]}; j++)); do
        echo -e "${fields[$i]}" "${fields[$j]}"'\t'"${values[$j]}"
    done
done < <( tail -n+2 "$INPUT")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy using `awk`.

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1.txt
snp1 snp1 1
snp1 snp2 0.3
snp1 snp3 0.4
snp1 snp4 0.5
snp2 snp1 0.3
snp2 snp2 1
snp2 snp3 0.4
snp2 snp4 0.5
snp3 snp1 0.4
snp3 snp2 0.4
snp3 snp3 1
snp3 snp4 0.5
snp4 snp1 0.5
snp4 snp2 0.5
snp4 snp3 0.5
snp4 snp4 1
```

Contents of `script.awk`. We skip the first line and format the rest as desired.

```
$ cat script.awk
{
if (NR == 1) next;
print $1" snp1 "$2;
print $1" snp2 "$3;
print $1" snp3 "$4;
print $1" snp4 "$5;
}
```

Contents of `file1.txt`

```
$ cat test.txt 
____   snp1  snp2   snp3   snp4
snp1    1     0.3   0.4    0.5  
snp2    0.3     1   0.4    0.5
snp3    0.4   0.4     1    0.5 
snp4    0.5   0.5   0.5      1
```

You can redirect the output to a new file like so.

```
awk -f script.awk file1.txt > file2.txt
```